# AD User Account Creation - Same Username

Tags: active-directory, exchange, user-management

Is there a way to setup AD and/or Exchange so that when 2 people with similar names are setup in AD it just adds the middle initial to the email instead of a number at the end?

Example:
 Jon Jacobs has a username of jjacobs and an email of jjacobs@example.com
His wife also works here and her name is Joan.  When she is added into AD it alters her username to be jajacobs as her middle name is ariel but her email now is listed as jjacobs2@example.com instead of jajacobs@example.com.

How can we alter this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not aware of a way to change the conflict behaviour.
You can change the email address policy, but that would affect all users.

I think most people would simply change the email address manually.

Answer (score 2):

In your question you said:

> When she is added into AD it alters her username

Active Directory would not just decide on its own to put that middle initial into the SAMAccountName.  SAMAccountName is a required field and must be supplied when making the account.  AD will throw an error upon account creation if there is a duplicate SAMAccountName in the domain.

When you create a mailbox Exchange will automatically assign an alias to the now mail enabled AD account if done some way other than through the EMC/ECP.  (It appears that through EMC/ECP alias is a required field -- but I have not tested to verify.)  It will try to match the alias to the SAMAccountName (alias is the Exchange term for what it that maps to the mailNickname AD attribute).  If there is a duplicate alias then it appends a number to the new alias that it creates.

But something is not adding up in your question.  You should not have duplicate aliases without having a duplicate SAMAccountName.  You can only have duplicate SAMAccountNames if you have Exchange in a forest with multiple domains.  Having said that Exchange will not allow you to enter a duplicate alias, however if something is editing the AD attribute mailNickname that is not a key field in AD and it allows duplicate values.

In the Exchange documentation the variable `%m` maps to the Exchange alias and it appears by your question that you have an email policy that looks like %m@contoso.com for your mail addresses.  *I just realized during my proofing that you could be using %1g%s and most of what I said should give you something to think about for moving to %m@contoso.com if you want to consider doing that.  So maybe you have %1g%s@contoso.com (1st letter of givenname/firstname and then sirname/lastname)*  [Technet article that has Exchange email address policy variables.](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb232171(v=exchg.150).aspx)

It appears to me that you need to review your process for AD account and then mailbox creation and see if there is a step in there that will help you deal better with this situation and catch duplicate values further up the chain.

Comment: You're correct JBaldridge, we are using %1g%s for 1st letter of given name/last name.

Answer (score 0):

One way to deal with this would be to change your naming convention for AD user accounts to include the middle initial, then change your E-Mail Address Policy to use a custom SMTP address that includes the given name, middle initial, and surname (%g %i %s).

Comment: I like the idea, even having %1g %i %s wouldn't be so bad.  I just don't like the idea of changing this globally.  The naming scheme would then be mixed.  I might just do as suggested and manually edit the email address through exchange admin center

Answer (score 0):

Try using a Powershell script for New-ADUser with try/catch or `-whatif` in order to find a duplicate AD user before you get to the point where Exchange renames the alias. Then you can use whatever logic you wish to get it named the way you want.